# Sequences of ±1 that have partial sum >2 is a Catalan number

Tags: combinatorics, catalan-numbers

We want to prove that the number of sequences $(a_1,...,a_{2n})$ such that
$$
• \text{ every } a_i \text{ is equal to} ±1;\\• a_1 + ··· + a_{2n} = 0;\\• \text{ every partial sum satisfies } a_1 + ··· + a_i > −2 
$$
is a Catalan number.

I've been trying to form a bijection between this and ballot sequences of size 2(n+1) by showing that you can remove any one +1 and any one -1 to yield our new sequences, but I am not sure if this is the best method. Any help would be super helpful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question is similar to the paths (0,2) to (2n,2) that do not touch X axis. The number of paths touches at least one point on the axis should be $2n \choose n+2$.
The total number of paths should be $2n \choose n$.
Then you can get the final answer, $2n \choose n+2$ - $2n \choose n$

Answer (score 1):

*Hint.* Catalan numbers $C_n$ can be used to count the number of "monotonic lattice paths along the edges of a grid with $n \times n$ square cells, which do not pass above the diagonal. A monotonic path is one which starts in the lower left corner, finishes in the upper right corner, and consists entirely of edges pointing rightwards or upwards" (quoted from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan_number#Applications_in_combinatorics)). Here you have the case $n=4$.

[image]

In order to describe the movements, let $a_i$ be the $i$-th movement and choose $a_i=1$ if you move to the right and $a_i=-1$ if you move upwards. Is it clear why $\sum a_i=0$? And why every $a_i$ is equal to $\pm 1$? Why do they satisfy $a_1+a_2+\ldots+ a_k<-2$ (look at the diagonal)?