# Catalan Numbers: Sequence of -1 and 1 that sums to 0 with conditions

Tags: combinatorics, integer-lattices, catalan-numbers

There is a relatively simple bijection between 0-sum sequences of 1 and -1 where the sum of all partial sequences is nonnegative and Dyck paths - this is very easy to count as a Catalan number.

However, I was trying to think about this problem with the condition that the partial sums are greater than some value, say $-5$, i.e.

Let $S$ be some $2n$ length sequence consisting of $n$ $1$s and $n$ $-1$s such that $\sum_{i=1}^{2n} S_i = 0$. Then, how many sequences $S$ exist such that the partial sum $\sum_{i=1}^{k} S_i > -5$ for all $k \in [1, 2n]$?

I tried thinking about this by 'shifting' the diagonal to $y = x + 4$, or by starting at different points, but I can't quite figure out how to count it. I also found [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3851650/sequences-of-%C2%B11-that-have-partial-sum-2-is-a-catalan-number), but the solutions did not really help much.

Comment: You will find your answer embedded in [OEIS A050157](https://oeis.org/A050157).  So ${2n \choose n}-{2n \choose n+5}$, setting the second term to $0$ when $n<5$.  The original Catalan numbers are  ${2n \choose n}-{2n \choose n+1}$

Comment: Let "bad" sums be the ones whose partial sums do reach $-5$. Find the first summand where that occurs (it has to be a -1), then switch +1's and -1's everywhere _after_ that special -1. Check that: 1) after the switch you end up having $n+5$ -1's and $n-5$ +1's; 2) the position of the special -1 in the original sum is recoverable from the new sum; 3) any sum of $n+5$ -1's and $n-5$ +1's must have partial sums reach $-5$ at least once. Thus, the number of "bad" sums is $\binom{2n}{n+5}$.